# Persistent and temporary stores in react native

Tags: react-native, realm

I'm absolutely new to React and React Native, I've read concepts and tried to create a demo app.

Now, I'm going to create a real app and I faced the question:

I need to have two database - one which I will able to update with app updates and one which will store user saved data and shouldn't be updated afterwards.

How can I realize it?

I will use Realm.

I'm sorry for so stupid question from a newbie.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can specify that a Realm is read-only (see property `readOnly` in https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/api/Realm.html#~Configuration). Of course, you will have to write your user data first, close the instance and open it read-only thereafter.

The other Realm is opened without setting `readOnly` which means you can update it.

It is not possible to share objects between Realms.